# Python script time slider change colors not working in Maya 2018

Tags: python, time, slider, maya

I  have  python script  which  change the color of the Maya time slider keyframes to any color  however  only runs on versions below the 2016 version of Maya, I need it to be upgraded to Maya versions 2017, 2018 and future versions of Maya.
I don't know about what  are libraries should be included or changed  for  Maya  2018.
The  script  source  code is in  this URL  [Time  Slider  Changed  colors](http://www.djalmabright.h-br.com/maya/colorkey-1.py)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attributes `useCurveColor` and `curveColor` to change the key colors.

This will change the keys to blue on selected objects:

```
for obj in cmds.ls(sl=True):
    anim_curves = cmds.listConnections(obj, type="animCurve") or []
    if anim_curves:    
        cmds.setAttr("{}.useCurveColor".format(anim_curves[0]), True)
        cmds.setAttr("{}.curveColor".format(anim_curves[0]), 0, 1, 1) # Must be values between 0.0 - 1.0
```

Just note that this will change ALL keys from a given attribute. As far as I know you can't change them individually.